# Dynamics - Deriving Linear acceleration based on angle theta

Tags: dynamics

Suppose that I am given an equation of some positional vector in the Cartesian coordinate system that is based on some theta shown right below.

[image: Question]

I am asked to find the linear acceleration based on these positional vectors (in terms of the variables), so naturally I derived twice for each of these equations.

So for example for x1''(t) I tried (though I am not clear if I did this properly):

$x_1''\left(t\right)=\:f''\left(\theta \left(t\right)\right)\cdot \theta ''\left(t\right)$

So if my x1(t) equals:

$x_1\left(t\right)\:=\:-r_1cos\left(\theta _1\left(t\right)-90^{\circ} \right)$

Would my x1''(t) be $r_1cos\left(\theta _1\left(t\right)-90^{\circ} \right)\cdot \theta _1'\left(t\right)+r_1sin\left(\theta _1\left(t\right)-90^{\circ} \right)\cdot \theta _1''\left(t\right)$ ???

And for x2''(t) what would be a proper way of deriving the equation in terms of the variable now there are multiple variables?? Would it be something like this?

$x_2\left(t\right)=\:f''\left(\theta _1\:\left(t\right),\theta _2\left(t\right)\right)\cdot \:\theta _1\:''\left(t\right)\cdot \theta _2''\left(t\right)$

My question seems very basic (and it honestly is )and I am asking how to derive twice properly with variables but dynamics problem seems to have its own notations for everything. Please helpmeout

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you’re doing 2d joint kinematics! We can think of this as an exercise in the chain rule. We can apply the following for any function describing position w.r.t time, $\theta$ just happens to be the problem at hand.

#### Linear Velocity

Linear Velocity is the first derivative of position with respect to time, which can be computed as:

$\frac{dx_1}{dt} = \frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{d\theta}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{dt}$

Where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{d\theta}{dt}$  is the portion of linear velocity caused by rotation, and $\frac{\partial f}{dt}$ is the linear velocity of the mechanism independent of rotation. So if your mechanism were mounted on a car, the first term is the velocity of the point $x_1$ if the car were stationary, and the second term is the velocity of the car. It sounds like $\frac{\partial f}{dt} = 0$ for your problem.

#### Linear Acceleration

Differentiating again, we use everybody’s favorite rule, the product rule.

$\frac{d^2x_1}{dt^2} =  \frac{d^2f}{dt^2} =  (\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{d\theta}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}) + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial t}$

In the same analogy: $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial t}$ is the acceleration of the car, and the parenthesized pair of terms are the contribution of angular acceleration and angular velocity to linear acceleration. Recall that a constant circular motion implies an inward acceleration.

If $f$ does not vary directly with time, every term is zero except $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}$, the angular acceleration term,

With many arguments (thetas in your case), we can write:

$$\frac{d^2x_n}{dt^2} =  \frac{d^2f}{dt^2} =  \sum_{n=1}^{N} (\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial \theta_n \partial t} \frac{d\theta_n}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_n} \frac{d^2\theta_n}{dt^2}) + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial t}$$